# Dataflow job failed error: insufficient quota(s) with 0 CPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, quota

I am new to GCP and working on creating dataflow job using Text file on cloud storage to pub/sub template. But Job failed with the following error

> Workflow failed. Causes: Project XXYYZZ has insufficient quota(s) to execute this workflow with 1 instances in region asia-south1. Quota summary (required/available): 1/8 instances, ***4/0 CPUs***, 430/2048 disk GB, 0/250 SSD disk GB, 1/100 instance groups, 1/50 managed instance groups, 1/100 instance templates, 1/4 in-use IP addresses.

It is clear that error is because of 0 CPU. Permission given is Admin/Owner permission.

How to handle this error?

Comment: Is it your own personal project? Do you already have some VM running on this project?

Comment: Are you using a Free Trial account? If, yes you cannot request a quota change. Did you enable billing for your account? If no, the same issue. Check if you have quota available in another region such as us-central. This link has details on how to request a quota increase: https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas

Comment: To expand on the above comments, 4/0 CPUs implies that your full CPU quota is in use, likely by other services in the project. So your solution is to either free up some CPUs or increase your quota.

Comment: I changed the region to us-central1, it worked :) So CPU quota for Mumbai region was completely utilized. Thank you all :)